# What does public.onChange = Function.prototype do?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I was scratching my head when i was trying to find some sample code for designing an inline editing form input component in Angular 5. I ran accross the following lines:

```
public onChange: any = Function.prototype; 
public onTouched: any = Function.prototype;
```

My question is: What do they do? The example then goes on and implements the `ControlValueAccessor` interface. It would implement some members like this:

```
public registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => {}): void {
  this.onChange = fn;
}

public registerOnTouched(fn: () => {}): void {
  this.onTouched = fn;
}
```

So it seems you would assign some function to the global Function prototype. Is that good practice and what is the author trying to do with that?

Comment: Maybe they wanna `this.onChange.call(context)` to not throw an error. However they are definetly not using typescript the right way. I mean `any` is definetly not the right type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's safe to assume that these methods are used as hooks, and making them functions unconditionally is a way for developers to avoid `if (typeof onChange  === 'function')` checks before calling them.

`Function.prototype` is a prototype of all regular functions, basically noop function. Accidentally modifying its properties (unlikely but possible) will affect all existing functions, e.g. `onChange.apply = ...`.

More safe, conventional and readable way is to just assign noop value explicitly:

```
public onChange: any = () => {};
```

Answer (score 1):

The

```
public onChange: any = Function.prototype;
```

assigns the reference of Function.prototype to the public onChange member variable, which is meant to be a callable function. In this case a function that does nothing when initalised.

That way, you can always call the onChange function without a crash.

The registerOnChange function will overwrite this reference, not add a function to the global prototype. To do that, the code would look something like

```
this.onChange['thisIsAGlobalFunction'] = fn;
// Square brackets and not dot-notation because of type-checking
```

This allows a programmer to optionally register event handlers.